# BeautifulSoup scrape data and save in text file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

im trying to create a table scraper, I’ve written this code http://pastebin.com/t1wSPvbb
But i have problem with saving data in text, after 10 page the scraper save same data

this is the code whit problem :

```
for num in range(1,500):
    print num
    try:
        resp = ''
        resp = opener.open("http://login.site.com/view.asp?view&PAGE="+str(num))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read())
        for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[3:]:
                tds = tr.find_all('td')
                outfile.write (tds[2].text.encode('utf-8','replace') + ',' +  tds[0].text.encode('utf-8','replace') + ',' + tds[1].text.encode('utf-8','replace') + '\n')
                
                pass
    except:
        pass
```

After 10 pages, the scraper saves the same data for the next few pages.

Comment: are you sure if you enter the page number manually its not just 10 pages of results? for me that url always gives the same content ...

Comment: no, i have this script whit regex and work, the pages not give the same content !